# go-router returning 'Null' is not subtype of String

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-go-router

I'm trying to **go-router** on my routing.
First time it works but once I refresh it works.

```
final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
  debugLogDiagnostics: true,
  initialLocation: '/',
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
        return const MainPage();
      },
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: '/product/:id',
      name: 'product',
      builder: (context, state){
        final id = state.params['id']!;
        return DetailsView(id:id);
        },
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: '/homepage',
      builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
        return const HomePage();
      },
    ),
  ],
);
```

Even when passing any value it doesn't work

```
onTap: () {
        context.pushNamed("product", params: {'id':"dsadklaskld"});
   
      },
```

Here is the stateful widget which I'm navigating to.
**detailsView.dart**

```
class DetailsView extends StatefulWidget {
  final String id;

  /// Constructs a [DetailsScreen]
  const DetailsView({super.key, required this.id});
  @override
  State<DetailsView> createState() => _DetailsViewState();
}
class _DetailsViewState extends State<DetailsView> {
.... 
  late String id = widget.id;
}
```

Comment: Solutions/Answers go below, remove it from your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of id was null so I had to put it in initializedata() function.